# SupportMapFragment not found

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I am trying to get Google Maps Android API v2 working on Android 2.2 on a HTC Desire.

My main.xml contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dk.sw510e13.user"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="dk.sw510e13.user.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my activity.

```
package dk.sw510e13.user;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

When I run the application, I will get the following exception. It seems that it cannot find SupportMapFragment, however, I believe that I have both the support library and Google Play Services as dependencies. When creating the project in Android Studio I chose to add support for fragments.

```
01-17 23:52:55.237    2557-2557/dk.sw510e13.user E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dk.sw510e13.user/dk.sw510e13.user.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:582)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1654)
        at dk.sw510e13.user.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
        ... 11 more
        Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:409)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
        ... 20 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/dk.sw510e13.user-2.apk]
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:399)
        ... 23 more
```

This is what I have in my dependencies.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dk.sw510e13.user"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="dk.sw510e13.user.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXX"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your manifest

Comment: @Anchit I have updated my question to show the manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem that seems to be occurred when missing Google Play services.

I request you to please follow the steps mentioned below to get the Google Play services to be included in your application.

**copying the google-play-services.jar in libs folder and set in the build path of eclipse is a wrong method.**

1. import Google Play services in your project and add it in workspace.
   from location of your SDK folder.

**\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib**

2! Now you added Google Play Services to your work space, we have to create a reference
from our project to this library. Right-Click your project and choose “Properties” go
to the Android section, in the lower part press the “Add…” button and add a reference
to that library. Your result should be as in the screen shot bellow:

adding Google Play services library

[image]

Please Add

```
<permission
        android:name="com.anchit.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

in your manifest

Comment: I am using Android Studio and I believe that I have correctly referenced the library. Please check the screenshot in the bottom of my original post. Isn't this right?

Comment: Ended up setting the whole thing up in Eclipse following yours and Googles instructions. This works. I'm not sure exactly what went wrong when using Android Studio. Thanks for your answer.